# How do I group by month the count of a column?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get the total number (count) of a column grouped by month.

For example.

```
c1   - c2 - c3
Dev  - A  - 2018-05-15
Dev  - B  - 2017-06-23
Dev  - C  - 2018-12-11
Fro  - D  - 2018-12-11
Dev  - E  - 2018-12-16
```

This means that Dev had two transactions in Dec 2018... I want to write a MySQL query that would result in something like

```
Dev - June-2017 - 1
Dev - May-2018 - 1
Dev - Dec-2018 - 2
Fro - Dec-2018 - 1
```

I want it to show the count for Dev(and the others) for each month.

Here is what I have come up with but it never executes (workbench simply says "query interrupted").

```
SELECT c1, DATE_FORMAT(c2, "%M-%Y") AS c2, COUNT(c1) 
  FROM table 
  WHERE condition    
GROUP BY c2;
```

Comment: "never executes"? What does that mean?

Comment: topicstarters MySQL server has probably ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled as a sql_mode @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Workbench just says "Query Interrupted".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For correct results you need to add column c1 within the GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
   c1
 , DATE_FORMAT(c2, "%M-%Y") AS c2
 , COUNT(c1) AS count
FROM 
 [table]
WHERE 
 [condition]
GROUP BY
   c1
 , DATE_FORMAT(c2, "%M-%Y")
ORDER BY 
 c1 ASC
```